# Linux birtviewer error on flat file: invalid table name

Tags: birt, actuate

I have developed a report that is using a flat file for some parameter values. It runs fine in birt designer but when I run it on birtviewer in linux environment, I get the below error

```
Table (id = 4172):
+ An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Failed to prepare the query execution for the data set: distinct qmid
Failed to prepare the following query for the data set type (org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.dataSet). 
[select "qmid" from "qmids.csv" : {"qmid","qmid",INT}]
    org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.InvalidResourceException: Invalid table name:qmids.csv
```

Can someone please guide what is this error about and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There is a bug in Birt that it gives some problem with relative path on flat files. Try to use the absolute path and it should work fine

Arif